# In Rails app, download a PDF file generated from a scrape

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, download

I made the following code on Ruby, that :

- logins in a specific site
- scrapes a link
- downloads a PDF file

As the code is tested and works fine, now I want to use it in Rails app. As the download starts automatically, I put the code in a “download” controller (homepage.com/download) adding this part in the controller:

```
send_file file, :filename => my_pdf.pdf, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
```

Hoping that when the user clicks on the link “homepage.com/download” the file will be downloaded, but nothing happens.

Below the full code:

```
begin

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::File
page = agent.get("http://www.example.com")

#login
form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_mail"
form.password = "my_password"
page = form.submit


# parse the link
agent.get("http://www.example.com/").parser.xpath('//div/a').each do |link|


# download the file
File.open("/my_pdf.pdf", 'w+b') do |file|
file << page.body.strip

# the new part that I added on rails
send_file file, :filename => my_pdf.pdf, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"

end
end
```

What’s wrong with the code? 
Do I have to add something in my **View** ? in my **Routes** ?

By the way, I am not sure that this part :

File.open("**/my_pdf.pdf**", 'w+b') do |file|

is right in Rails application, because on Ruby, the file is saved in Public folder of the application, not sure that it works the same way on ROR 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of need, I found the answer:

If the file is saved in Public folder, just replace the last part of my code

```
send_file file, :filename => my_pdf.pdf, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
```

by this one

```
Rails.root.join('public', 'my_pdf.pdf')
```

And the file will be downloaded